# ReactJs Antd - window.open an url dynamically

Tags: reactjs, antd

Im using the below code to open an url on a popup window.

```
{
        title: 'Contract',
        dataIndex: 'index',
        key: 'contract',
        render: (text,record,index) =>
            <button onClick={() => window.open({record.contract}, "Popup","width=600, height=600")}>
              Open
            </button>
      },
```

The issue is that i can't call the object value **`{record.contract}`**.
It throws the `Unexpected token, expected ","` error.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unexpected Token errors normally happen when your the programming syntax is not correct.

`{record.contract}` is not valid syntax.

when passing to a method inside an event, you should use the variable name directly.
the correct syntax for your button will be:

```
<button onClick={() => window.open(record.contract, "Popup","width=600, height=600")}>
    Open
</button>
```

This will solve the unexpected token error.